# PHP, undefined index, isset and radio buttons

Tags: php, isset

I have a form and I'm doing input validation, so when the user inputs something wrong I generate an error message and refill all the fields the user entered.

Now, some errors popped up when I started using the php.ini file for mysql stuff, such as

```
Undefined index: var in file.php on line n
```

For a simple text input (a title) I was able to fix this fairly easily, by doing

```
value="<?= isset($_POST["title"]) ? $_POST["title"] : "";?>"
```

However, I'm also using 5 radio buttons to give a rating, like this:

```
value="1" <?= $_POST["grade"] == "1" ? "checked" : "" ?>
value="2" <?= $_POST["grade"] == "2" ? "checked" : "" ?>
etc
```

I tried applying the isset bandage here as well,

```
value="1" <?= isset($_POST["grade"] == "1") ? "checked" : "" ?>
```

but as I was quickly reminded, isset only works with variables and arrays, not booleans.

What would be an appropriate way to solve this?

Comment: Could you please try replace the `<?=` with `<?php` and try again?

Comment: who told that isset doesn't work for boolean?

Comment: @MerianosNikos If they replace `<?=` with `<?php`, it won't output anything. `<?=` is just a shorter way of writing `<?php echo`

Comment: @MagnusEriksson I just thought that maybe changed something in the php.ini that affects the short opening tags. Without a full code example, it's not that easy to help.

Comment: @MerianosNikos - The shorthand `<?=` is available regardless of the short open tags setting.

Comment: @OMiShah phpstorm did, giving the "isset only works with variables and arrays" error when attempting the last line in the OP

Comment: That's because you can't have an expression `$_POST["grade"] == "1"` in `isset()` since that function checks if a the variable (or array index) exists and isn't null.

Comment: `<?= (isset($_POST["grade"]) && $_POST["grade"] == "1") ? "checked" : "" ?>`

Comment: Please do not post resolving advice as a comment -- that is why Stack Overflow offers answers as a posting option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first thing you have to do is check whether the variable is set or not. Then you can append your comparison with an operator.

```php
value="1" <?= isset($_POST["grade"]) && $_POST["grade"] == "1" ? "checked" : "" ?>
```

Comment: That does indeed work, thank you!

I attempted something similar before but I must have gotten the syntax or order wrong.

Comment: @Robin you are frequently answering question, but I am not noticing a lot closing.  Please understand that  after 10 years of feverish Q&A, all basic php questions are duplicates.  Please vote to close duplicate questions.